# PDF-A1a document not valid after signing with VisualRepresentation using IText

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I digitally sign a PDF-A1a document using IText 7.15.0.

In addition to the digital signature, I also add a visual representation (image) to the document.

```cs
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
appearance.SetPageNumber(1);

Rectangle pr = new Rectangle(10 + ImageOffset, 10 + ImageOffset, 100, 100 );
appearance.SetPageRect(pr);
byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(VisualAppearance);

appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(image);
appearance.SetSignatureGraphic(imageData);
```

This code works and the signature is valid.
But if the document was a PDF-A1a, it is no longer a valid PDF-A1a. It only becomes invalid when I add the visual representation. If I just apply the signature without the visual representation, it remains a valid PDF-A1a.

Other PDF-A standards like A2a do remain valid when adding the visual representation.

When using foxit phantom to validate the PDF-A1a, it shows the following message:

> A transparent soft mask is present. Beginning with PDF 1.4 transparency is supported. Some PDF-based ISO standards prohibit the use of transparency.

What do i need to do in order to keep a PDF-A1a valid while adding the visual representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Foxit already informs, some standards prohibit the use of transparency within a conforming file, in particular ISO 19005-1 does for PDF/A-1 profiles by a number of provisions, among them:

> If an **SMask** key appears in an **ExtGState** or **XObject** dictionary, its value shall be *None*.

*(ISO 19005-1, section 6.4 Transparency)*

But if iText adds an image with transparency information to a PDF, it translates the transparency information to a non-vanishing **SMASK** entry of the resulting image **XObject**.

To prevent this, simply use images without transparency.

In [a comment to your parallel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024482/howto-keep-pdf-a-when-signing-a-document-using-itext-signdeferred#comment114977026_65026882) you confirm

> If i use jpeg instead of png, the PDF-A1a remains valid.

For non-rectangular image outlines consider using a clip path.